# Invalid Input Data on arcpy.SelectByLocation_management

Tags: arcpy, layers, select-by-location, error-000368

I keep getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\drafting9\Drafting9\ShanePrice\Scripts\Python\Scripts\Cruise_Plan\Cruise_Plan_Model_Final_SP.py", line 77, in <module>
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(Cruise_Plots, 'INTERSECT', Timber_Type_Polygon)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 7320, in SelectLayerByLocation
    raise e
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000368: Invalid input data.
Failed to execute (SelectLayerByLocation).


Failed to execute (CruisePlan).
```

from the arcpy.SelectByLocation.management line towards the end of this script.

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy
import os
#arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

arcpy.Delete_management("in_memory")

# Script Parameters
Timber_Type_Polygon = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
Cell_Size_Height = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
Cell_Size_Width = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
Output_Coordinate_System = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
Output_Folder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)


# Set Geoprocessing environments
arcpy.env.outputCoordinateSystem = Output_Coordinate_System
arcpy.env.geographicTransformations = ""

# Process: Project
arcpy.AddMessage('...Projecting TimberType to Desired Projection')
arcpy.Project_management(Timber_Type_Polygon, os.path.join(Output_Folder, "Cruise_Polygon.shp"), Output_Coordinate_System, "", "PROJCS['NAD_1983_BC_Environment_Albers',GEOGCS['GCS_North_American_1983',DATUM['D_North_American_1983',SPHEROID['GRS_1980',6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION['Albers'],PARAMETER['False_Easting',1000000.0],PARAMETER['False_Northing',0.0],PARAMETER['Central_Meridian',-126.0],PARAMETER['Standard_Parallel_1',50.0],PARAMETER['Standard_Parallel_2',58.5],PARAMETER['Latitude_Of_Origin',45.0],UNIT['Meter',1.0]]", "NO_PRESERVE_SHAPE", "", "NO_VERTICAL")

NAR_U9 = os.path.join(Output_Folder, "Cruise_Polygon.shp")

# Process: Create Fishnet
desc = arcpy.Describe(NAR_U9)
arcpy.AddMessage('...Generating Cruise Grid')
arcpy.CreateFishnet_management("in_memory/fishnet", str(desc.extent.XMin) + " " + str(desc.extent.YMin), str(desc.extent.XMin) + " " + str(desc.extent.YMin + 10), Cell_Size_Width, Cell_Size_Height, "0", "0", str(desc.extent.XMax) + " " + str(desc.extent.YMax), "NO_LABELS", NAR_U9, "POLYLINE")

# Process: Clip
arcpy.AddMessage('...Clipping Grid to Block Area')
arcpy.Clip_analysis("in_memory/fishnet", NAR_U9, os.path.join(Output_Folder, "Cruise_Grid.shp"), "")

Cruise_Grid = os.path.join(Output_Folder, "Cruise_Grid.shp")

# Process: Intersect
arcpy.AddMessage('...Generating Cruise Plots')
arcpy.Intersect_analysis(Cruise_Grid, "in_memory/plots_before_dissolve", "NO_FID", "", "POINT")

# Process: Add XY Coordinates
arcpy.AddXY_management("in_memory/plots_before_dissolve")

# Process: Dissolve
arcpy.Dissolve_management("in_memory/plots_before_dissolve", os.path.join(Output_Folder, "Cruise_Plots.shp"), "POINT_X;POINT_Y", "", "SINGLE_PART", "DISSOLVE_LINES")

Cruise_Plots = os.path.join(Output_Folder, "Cruise_Plots.shp")

# Process: Add Sort Field
arcpy.AddField_management(Cruise_Plots, "Plot_ID", "SHORT", "", "", "5", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")

# Sort Plots
arcpy.AddMessage('...Sorting Plots')
cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(Cruise_Plots, "", Output_Coordinate_System, "POINT_Y; POINT_X", "POINT_Y ASCENDING; POINT_X ASCENDING")

counter = 1
for row in cursor:
    row.Plot_ID = counter
    cursor.updateRow(row)
    counter += 1

# Process: Add Field (2)
arcpy.AddField_management(Cruise_Plots, "Type", "TEXT", "", "", "5", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")

# Process: Calculate Field
arcpy.CalculateField_management(Cruise_Plots, "Type", "Reclass(!Plot_ID!)", "PYTHON", "def Reclass (Plot_ID):\\n  if Plot_ID % 2: \\n    return \"M\"\\n  else :\\n    return \"C\"\\n\\n\\n")

# Count Total Plots in Each TimberType
arcpy.AddMessage('Counting Plots in Each Timber Type')
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(Timber_Type_Polygon, ['PLOTS']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(Cruise_Plots, 'INTERSECT', Timber_Type_Polygon)
        number_of_plots = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(Cruise_Plots).getOutput(0))
        row[0] = number_of_plots
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

To me the parameters make sense and it should work, shouldn't it? Or do the referenced parameters still need to be within quotations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/select-layer-by-location.htm:

> The input must be a feature layer; it cannot be a feature class.

`Cruise_Plots` is a shapefile, not a layer. Select by Location or Select by Attributes both need an input of layers, not feature classes. Use `arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(Cruise_Plots, "Cruise_Plots_lyr")` and then call with

`arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("Cruise_Plots_lyr", 'INTERSECT', Timber_Type_Polygon)`